# Schedule a google calendar invite for a specific time via calendar api

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am able to create google calendar events via its API. However, the email invite is sent immediately, the moment I create the event via API.

I want the event invite to be send few minutes before the event start time. So that users can respond to it as yes or no for their immediate availability.

Comment: Then do not invite them until a few minutes before? If you can't do this with the actual Calendar app / UI, you aren't going to achieve it with the Calendar  REST API.

Comment: For that I might have to run a cron to invite them just before the event, which I don't want to, and obviously, there will be many events, which the cron will have to look.